# Question about squares of the coefficients of variation

Tags: variance, mean, coefficient-of-variation

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable with any distribution that takes only positive values. Can the following inequality hold for constants  $c_2 >c_1 >0$?

$$\text{Var}(Z^{c_2})/\text{E}[Z^{c_2}]^2  > \text{Var}(Z^{c_1})/\text{E}[Z^{c_1}]^2$$

In other words:

$$\text{E}[Z^{2c_2}]/\text{E}[Z^{c_2}]^2  > \text{E}[Z^{2c_1}]/\text{E}[Z^{c_1}]^2$$

where $Z=X+1$.

With many thanks for your answer.

Comment: How is $z$ a random variable?

Comment: The notation is a bit muddled, x is a random variable with any distribution that takes only positive values. and z=x+1.The last formula is

Comment: x (not X) is a random variable with any distribution that takes only positive values. Also, the last formula is E[z^2c2]/E[z^c2]^2>E[z^2c1]/E[z^c1]^2

Comment: I would rephrase the question as: given a r.v. $Z \geqslant 1$, is it possible to have $\textrm{CV}(Z^b) >  \textrm{CV}(Z^a)$ with $ b >a$? Or: is it true that the CV of $Z^a$ is always an increasing function of $a$?

Comment: Sorry. In my last comment, the 2nd question should be : is it true that the CV of $Z^a$ is always an *decreasing* function of $a$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears  that the coefficient of variation $\textrm{CV}(Z^c)$ of $Z^c$  is increasing in $c$ 
provided that $Z > 0 $ with probability one. Indeed with $f(c) := \textrm{CV}^2(Z^c)+1$
for $c > 0$, we  have
$$
   f(c) = \frac{\textrm{E}[Z^{2c}]}{\textrm{E}^2[Z^c]} =  \frac{\textrm{E}[e^{2c Y}]}{\textrm{E}^2[e^{c Y}]} =  
   \frac{m_Y(2c)}{m_Y^2(c)}
$$
where  $Y:= \log Z$  and  $ m_Y(c) := \textrm{E}[e^{c Y}]$ is the moment generating
function of $Y$. A quite well-known fact is  that a moment generating function
is  *log-convex* on the interval where it exists. 
Thus $r(c) := \log m_Y(c)$ defines a convex function of
$c$. Now $\log f(c) = r(2c) - 2 \,r(c)$, and for $c > 0$
$$ 
 \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}c} \log f(c)= 2 \,r'(2c) - 2\,r'(c) \geqslant 0
$$
since the derivative $r'(c)$ is increasing. Thus $\log f(c)$ is
increasing for $c >0$, and so is $\textrm{CV}(Z^c)$.

Note that $\textrm{CV}(Z^c)$ exists when
the moment of order $c$ of $Z^2$ is finite. This condition holds on an
interval with upper end-point $c^\star \geq 0$ depending on the distribution of
$Z$. The value of $c^\star$ can be finite and even be $0$ for some heavy tailed distributions.
The preceding derivation is valid for $0 < c < c^\star$, hence assumes that $c^\star>0$.

Comment: Now, assume that $Y=(Z^c)-1$ which $Z$ is a random variable that takes positive values larger than 1 and $c>0$. Is $\text{CV}^2(Y)$ (the square of coefficient of variation of $Y$) ascending in $c$? I tested this by simulation for some distributions, and the answer was yes. Thanks a million for your answer.

Comment: @user26409 It seems you've lost your account information. Please follow the instructions on our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) to merge your user profiles.